# What data visualization tools/BI tools to use in web application?

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, node.js, charts, business-intelligence

I am developing web application using ReactJS, facebook Flux architecture, and ExpressJS (NodeJS framework). Database is MongoDB.

I will save some csv's in DB and present this data on web application UI through line charts/bar charts/dashboards etc. For this I am using C3.js (D3-based reusable chart library). But it don't have all the features I am looking for.  So I am looking for new visualization or BI tools.

My requirements are

1. Charts on UI should be flexible and interactive. Like drag and drop filters on UI etc
2. Should be able to add custom visualizations/filters/drag and drops.
3. The tool/library should be compatible with my web-app technologies.

I should be able to use it in my web application.

I am looking through various tools like Microsoft PowerBI, Tableau, Qlik, Micro Strategy etc etc.